# How to remove bathtub faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I bought a house and the home inspector missed this about the spare bathtub:  when you turn on the cold water, water leaks out of the stem of the hot water faucet (and vice versa).  I figure the o rings need replacement (or maybe packing).  I finally got the faucet handles removed (screws were seized) and I see this odd shaped nut.  It seems to be attached to the valve--if I try to unscrew it, the water comes on.  The plastic chromed shroud prevents me from seeing anything.  So, do I simply turn off the water supply, and unscrew this all the way?  In other words, will it remove the valve stem?  Or will the valve "bottom out" and then I can remove this nut?

It's a three handle tub fixture from Kohler, maybe the original one (house built around 1965).  I'm skittish because both bathrooms share the same pipe so if something goes wrong, I lose the ability to shower.

UPDATE:  I found the part number of that piece:  it's a Kohler 41240-CP Insert Sub-Assembly.  Amazon has it (with picture):  [Kohler 41240](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002J3D26K).  The only difference is that has a washer under the nut (mine lacks it).  Someone on Amazon actually asked how to remove it and the answer was to use a faucet puller.  Is this true?  The hole is a 1/2 inch deeper than the rod on my faucet puller and that flimsy chromed plastic couldn't take much stress.  I did manage to find installation instructions for a Kohler Flair 3 handle faucet and the diagrams look like my faucet.  I will need to pull that insert off.  I'll try to extend my faucet puller with a nail and duct tape.  I'll let everyone know how it turns out.

Thanks for looking.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The ring against the tub wall should unscrew - it's likely only cosmetic.  And the cylinder just behind the "odd" nut maybe also.  Can you hold the nut with a wrench and twist off the cylinder and/or ring?

Comment: Yes, the ring against the tub might unscrew.  But, I need to get that cover off first.  I posted another picture to show it better.  That cover spins freely, so once the nut comes off, it should just slide off.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called Kohler support.  They told me "it just pulls off".  I was disappointed with that--nothing after 5 years "just pulls off".

I ended up tapping the hole. It's just the right size for a 1/4-20 tap.  I then used a bolt to pull the inserts off--just screw the bolt in until it hits the valve stem and it pulls it off.  I'm enclosing a picture of the inside of that insert so others can see what this is.
[image]

Comment: It's great that you got this fixed and thanks for coming back to tell us about it! Please give yourself a check-mark, too, so others know that there's a working solution. You'd have been hard-pressed to get enough WD-40 in there to work the corrosion & calcium loose - good thinking on threading it.